# jquery val() not working for hidden field

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden filed and trying to set a value inside a function . But its not working . Tried all the work around.

1.The .val() set is inside a function.
2.The function is not inside document.ready. If i move the function to document.ready , its not getting called.

```
         <script  type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#loadingModal').css('display', 'none');
             $('#loadingModal').css('left', '-500px');


         }); //end ready
         function buttonExportNotify() {
             debugger;
             blockUIForDownload();
         }

     var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
     function blockUIForDownload() {
         debugger;
         var token = new Date().getTime(); //use the current timestamp as the token value
         $("#download_token_value_id").val(token);

         $('#download_token_value_id').attr('value', token);
         //$.blockUI();
         $('#loadingModal').show();
         fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
             var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
             if (cookieValue == token)
                 finishDownload();
         }, 1000);
     }
     function finishDownload() {
         debugger;
         window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
         $.removeCookie('fileDownloadToken'); //clears this cookie value
         $('#loadingModal').hide();
     }</script>
```

HTML

```
   <input type="hidden" id="download_token_value_id" name="tri_download_token_value_id" runat="server"/>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="ExportExcel_LinkButton" runat="server" Text="Excel"   style="margin-left: 0px;" OnClientClick="buttonExportNotify()" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

**//below line not working**
         $("#download_token_value_id").val(token);

```
     $('#download_token_value_id').attr('value', token);
```

Thanks

Comment: @JosephMarikle added the HTML

Comment: That's not HTML.  That's ASP server-side markup.  We need the rendered HTML.  There's a possibility the ID is changed when the ASP markup is converted to HTML.  Although, I don't know for certain.  I'm not very familiar with ASP, but as you can see, jQuery does retrieve values from hidden fields: https://jsfiddle.net/2pmj2e52/

Comment: I think you need to use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) `$('#download_token_value_id').prop('value', token); ` instead of `attr`

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thank for pointing out .Yes ID is changed in html.        $("#MainContent_download_token_value_id").val(token);

Comment: @JosephMarikle Not sure how to accept your comment as answer.

Comment: @Vani It's not really an answer.  Have you tried bradlis7's response?  It's sounds like it might work.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that maybe the `id` is being changed by ASP. Try setting `clientidmode` in your hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="download_token_value_id" name="tri_download_token_value_id" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
```